# How to match specific letters in words

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm currently learning Russian, and there is one caveat in the encoding of Cyrillic letters: Some look exactly like ASCII. Example. The word »облако« (cloud) does neither contain an »a« nor an »o« but instead, it contains a »а« and a »о«. If you're not getting it yet, try to fire up your browsers search dialog, enter an »a« or an »o«, use some highlight-all functionality, and you will see, that »а« and »о« both remain dark.

So, now I want to highlight this problem in vim. Since I'm using mixed language text files, I can't just highlight every ASCII letter (that would be easy), instead, I want all ASCII letters in all words that contain at least one Cyrillic letter to be error-highlighted. My current approach is to use this matches:

```
" Here, I use бакло as a shortcut for the list of all cyrillic letters,
" this makes this a small self contained example for the word used in the
" problem desctiption, without having the full list in all lines.
" To get the file I actually have, run
" :%s/бакло/ЖжФфЭэЗзЧчБбАаДдВЬвьЪъЫыСсЕеёНнЮюІіКкМмИиЙйПпЛлОоРрЯяГгТтЦцШшЩщХхУу/g
syn match russianWordOk "[бакло]\+"

syn match russianWordError "[бакло][a-zA-Z0-9_]\+"hs=s+1
syn match russianWordError "[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+[бакло]"he=e-1
syn match russianWordError "[бакло][a-zA-Z0-9_]\+[бакло]"hs=s+1,he=e-1
```

However, like in »облaко« (now a is ASCII), the highlighting would still mark »обл« as valid, »a« as invalid, »к« as not being part of a keyword (it is part of the matching russianWordError keyword) and finally the remaining »о« as valid again. What I want instead is to have the entire word being part of the matching russianWordError keyword but still only the »a« being highlighted as illegal. Is there a way and if yes, how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to only match *whole words*, not fragments inside other words, wrap your patterns in `\<` and `\>`. These assertions will then be based on Vim's `'iskeyword'` setting, and should be fine. (Alternatively, you can do other lookbehind and lookahead assertions via `\@<=` and `\@=`.)

```
syn match russianWordOk "\<[бакло]\+\>"
```

I would approach the highlighting of the wrong ASCII character not via `hs=` / `he=`, but via a contained group. First, identify bad mixed words. There has to be at least one cyrillic letter, either at the beginning, or at the end. The rest is at least one (i.e. repeating the `\%(...\)` group with `\+`, or else you would only match single-error words) ASCII, potentially other cyrillics in between:

```
syn match russianWordBad "\<\%([бакло]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]\)\+[бакло]\+\>" contains=russianWordError
syn match russianWordBad "\<[бакло]\+\%([a-zA-Z0-9_][бакло]*\)\+\>" contains=russianWordError
```

This contains the ASCII syntax group that does the error highlighting. Because of `contained`, it only matches inside another group (here: `russianWordBad`).

```
syn match russianWordError "[a-zA-Z0-9_]" contained
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "\%("?

Comment: It starts a non-capturing group. Slightly more efficient than `\(`.